# Firefox add-on: Injected HTML

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I'm trying to write an add-on for firefox and i'm having a problem-
When the user right-clicking on the page the add-on is adding an element to the page's body using

```
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

myElement has a button and i want that "onClick" it will call a xmlHttpRequest and handle the response in some why. I've tried to inject the two scripts using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(xmlRequestFunction);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(handleResponseFunction);
```

but it didn't work because of (i assume) a security problem.
What can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `onclick` when working with content, use `addEventListener` instead (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Limitations_of_XPCNativeWrapper if you need to know why). Like this:

```
myElement.addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It is working- now I can send the request and I am getting "200 OK". I have a follow up question- How to handle the response? (it isn't synchronized connection, I think)

Comment: `request.onload = function() {...}`, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).